# AudioRecorder blocks microphone

Tags: android, audio-recording

I'm working on an app which allows user to take voice notes. For this I'm using the AudioRecorder to constantly obtain audio data from microphone and process it into Mp3.

It all worked great until recently I found out that if I receive/make a call while my app is running in background the other party can't hear me. Clicking on mute/unmute button on dialer screen doesn't do anything - the microphone seems to be disabled until I stop my app.

Now the question is how can I handle this situation? Is my only option is to release AudioRecorder once a voice call is started? I'm perfectly ok if AudioRecorder would just skip the audio data from microphone during the call, but the situation when user can communicate because of the app is unacceptable.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Only 1 app can use the mic at any given time.  You might want to use PhoneStateListener so that you can release the recorder when the phone rings or is off the hook.

Comment: You know, I don't see the problem on Nexus S running Android 4.1, however my HTC Sensation on Android 2.3.3 does suffer from this issue. So I'm wondering if the problem is HTC or Android version-specific

Comment: The difference may be that some device implementations force close your apps access to the mic.

Comment: Nope, the app happily runs in background

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept incoming calls using PHONE_STATE action as part of a BroadcastReceiver. Then, in your onReceive function of your receiver, you would check states of the phone:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
        //Phone is ringing

    }else if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK){
        //Call received


    }else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
        //Call Dropped or rejected

    }

}
```

Do not forget to add the neccessary permissions in your manifest.

Likewise, you can intercept outgoing calls as well. [Here](http://www.krvarma.com/2010/08/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-in-android/) is a nice tutorial explaining how to do both.

The rest is about stopping and resuming recorder depending on what you intercept.